# refreshcontrol endrefreshing has to wait for the subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, pull-to-refresh

I have a implemented a refreshcontrol for my tableview and it works fine. But I wanna achieve to invoke another class execute the process within that class. I want my refreshcontrol should wait until the execution of that class.

Eg: I have some database changes in the Player class. Now the refreshcontrol ends the refresh while the database changes are in progress.

```
-(void)pullToRefresh{
    UpdOther *updO = [[UpdOther alloc] initWithProfile:@"Player"];
    [updO release];
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having the `pullToRefresh` method wait for the update, it would be better if you simply used a completion block in your update process, so `pullToRefresh` could tell the update process what to do when the update was done.

For example, rather than having the `initWithProfile` perform the update process, you could have some method, say `performUpdateWithCompletion` do it, but give it a completion block:

```
- (void)performUpdateWithCompletion:(void (^)(void))completionBlock
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // do synchronous update here

        // when done, perform the `completionBlock`

        if (completionBlock) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                completionBlock();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Then your `pullToRefresh` can specify what it wants the update process to do upon completion, for example:

```
- (void)pullToRefresh{
    UpdOther *updO = [[UpdOther alloc] initWithProfile:@"Player"];
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [updO performUpdateWithCompletion:^{
        typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        [strongSelf.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }];
    [updO release];
}
```

There are other approaches, too, (delegate pattern, notification pattern), but I prefer the in-line immediacy of the block-based solution.

---

By the way, if `UpdOther` is using the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods, you obviously need to call the `completionBlock` from some other method (e.g., `connectionDidFinishLoading`). So, in that case, you'd define a block property in `UpdOther` as so:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^updateCompletionBlock)(void);
```

Or, you can define a `typedef` for this block:

```
typedef void (^UpdateCompletionBlock)(void);
```

and then use that in your property declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) UpdateCompletionBlock updateCompletionBlock;
```

Anyway, in that case, your `performUpdateWithCompletion` would save a copy of the block in that property:

```
- (void)performUpdateWithCompletion:(void (^)(void))completionBlock
{
    self.updateCompletionBlock = completionBlock;

    // now initiate time consuming asynchronous update here
}
```

And then, however you complete your download, you can call the saved completion block there:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // do whatever extra steps you want when completing the update

    // now call the completion block

    if (self.updateCompletionBlock) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.updateCompletionBlock();
        });
    }
}
```